# How to configure OKTA + AWS Client VPN Endpoint + OpenVPN Client

Tags: okta, openvpn, aws-vpn

I found this article that describes configuring to use the AWS VPN Client.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authenticate-aws-client-vpn-users-with-saml/

Our team is currently configured using the OpenVPN Client and we would like to keep using it -- (OpenVPN Client is so much better)

The issue seems to be where we Add the Application to OKTA. Our OKTA guy tells me there is no option to add OpenVPN as a client and that there is no "OIN template" to allow this.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: are you positive that OpenVPN supports SAML authentication? If so, your Okta guy only needs to configure generic SAML application

Comment: I found a template in the OKTA console from 2018–in only supports SWA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have functioning AWS Client VPN that authenticates with Okta.
I contacted AWS support and was told that SAML/Okta authentication only works with the AWS provided client.